# Access AngularJs application via link from email

Tags: angularjs

I need some suggestions from people who maybe had an experience with similar types of applications.
I am building and app that should be use for on line testing. For example if you want a job in some company, HR can create test session for you, and send you a link to an app.
That email will contain a link.
On link click I want to hit my angularjs app. AngularJs will get session id from the link it should make a request to server.
Server then needs to check db and try to find a test session with that Id, and return some response. (session data if it's ok or some message that session is expired, etc.)

The problem here is usage of JWT tokens. For example, when HR uses part of app, it has to be authenticated, which is done by jwt tokens.

What is the best practice when you have users on the other side? Like people who will take the test. They do not have jwt token, but server will expect something for authentication.

Should user get some custom token that will expired when test session expires, then maybe I can decode that token on angular side and check user role or something like that.

Did anybody had experience with building an app that can be access over a link?

Comment: And ? Does our answer helped you ?

Comment: @Weedoze Yes, and thank you very much. I your idea and I will try to implement it in that way and see will it work. For me the biggest problem here is that I think that we should have 2 separated applications. One for users who will take the test, and one for users who will create test sessions for them. But you know... an order is an order :)

Comment: Why should you have 2 applications ? You can have only 1 application with 2 differents links.. One for the creator and one for the testers

Comment: @Weedoze see the think that concerns me the most is this scenario. As psychologist I can enter my username and password, is I am auth server will give me jwt. First thought of the team was: Ok we can make jwt for test takers as well and send them inside the link or an email. But then who can be sure that users wont take advantage of it try to access parts of system they shouldn't. In case you suggest I will have to make controller without auth attribute and hope for the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible scenario

1. HR connect to the app and generate a new test session
2. Create a new test session in the database with all the necessary info + add 2 columns : `Token` + `Token_Expiration`. The `Token` will be a random string and the `Token_Expiration` is now + x hours
3. Send link with token to the user by email. *e.g* : *http://myapp.com/?token=ahdk5d5ek4945gol*
4. User click on the link that redirects him to the landing page.
5. Retrieve the token from the url and send it to the server
6. Server must check if this token exists inside the database

   - If the token does not exist - Forbidden access
   - If the token exists - Check if the current time does not exceed the `Token_Expiration`
7. User finish the test
8. Server must remove the `Token`or use a third column `Valid` and set it to `false`

Answer (score 1):

Send custom token with link and based on that authenticate user
then find session id for that custom token and return response 
and invalidate custom token after completion of test.